# Facebook test app register to facebook page created by test user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-test-users

My target is to test a new bot on facebook.

I got into a loophole trying to validate my bot... help to break; the loop :-)
Ok, I have prepared:

1. Facebook test app
2. Under the test app I generated a test user A and test user B.
3. With the test user A, I created a facebook page.
4. test user B can see test user A page and can message the page => so far so good.

now , here is the tricky part:

5. I try to register my test app to the **test user A page** and it's not working - I don't get an error, but I simply don't see it added to the page "apps".
   **So question is - can a test app register to a page generated by a test user?**
6. Without registering the page of Test user A, I can't see if the interaction between test user B and the page is triggering the bot.

Another option I tried -

7. When I try to register based on my own "real" account with one of my "real" pages to the app - all works well (registration wise), BUT! a test user B account can't message a "real page" to test it (based on facebook documentation), so again, I can't test my system.

**What am I missing?**